# Stretching only part of the letter

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have been trying to do this.

I have the word "Panther" and what I want is to stretch the letter "P" only to extend it and cover the other letter.

Here's what I am trying to accomplish. {I use paint so I just sketch it sorry}

[image]

I tried doing this but I am unsuccessful.

1. Create the text.
2. Convert the outline.

3.a I tried dragging the anchor point with the direct slection tool but I am not able to drag all anchor points along the curve of "P"

3.b I tried using the warp tool but it seems to skew the whole letter P.

Any hints?  Just picked up illustrator and learning the ropes.  Thanks.

Comment: I think 3.a is how I would handle this, depending on the anchor points available you might need to add some anchors in before dragging. Could you provide a screenshot of the outlined before and after attempts with the anchors visible?

Answer (score 6):

You could try this.

[image: Example Text Image]

Select your text and 'Create Outlines'. (MENU: Type>Create Outlines)

I select the text again and Ungroup everything. (MENU: Object>Ungroup)

Select the 'P' with the Selection Tool (V) and resize it appropriately while holding Shift to maintain proportions.

After I resize the 'P', I use 'Offset Path...' to remove the extra letter width. (MENU: Object>Path>Offset Path...)

[image: Example Text Image]

Next, you can use the Selection Tool (V) to select & remove the larger left-over 'P' surrounding your new path.

At this point, I position the 'anther' under the 'P'.

[image: Example Text Image]

Add extra anchor points to the horizontal section of the 'P' using the Add Anchor Point Tool (+).

[image: Example Text Image]

Lastly, use the Direct Selection Tool (A) to select **only** the anchor points in the bowl of the 'P', including the anchor points we just added. Click/Hold on a selected point and drag the selected section to the right while holding Shift.

[image: Example Text Image]

Once you're at this point, you can use some of those same steps and the Pen Tool (P) to do some other nifty things.

[image: Example Text Image]

I'm not an Illustrator wizard but this is hopefully a viable solution to your question.

Goodluck

Comment: Probably one of the best explained and formatted answers, I have ever encountered in the StackExchange.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the step which you can try and see the output :

1: Write the text you need to edit.
2: Select the text > go to object > expand > press ok.
3: Right click on the whole text and select ungroup.
4: now u can select the letter "P" individually and expand it.

Hope this helps